# Elevate command in a non-GUI environment

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change a line in a configuration file in `Program Files` folder.

I am connected to the Windows 7 machine with SSH, and the PowerShell version is 3.

What I am trying to run is:

```
$file = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TheApplication\config.xml'
$find = '  <Servername>old_value</Servername>'
$replace = ' <Servername>new_value</Servername>'

(Get-Content $file).Replace($find, $replace) | Set-Content $file
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Set-Content : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TheApplication\
>   config.xml' is denied.

If I try to run elevated PS, I get this error:

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs
```

> Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: This operation 
>   requires an interactive window station.

Is there any way to elevate the command to change file in the protected folder?

Comment: `Set-Content` does have a `-Credential` parameter and a `-Force`. Maybe this allready solves your problem? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Does not help. I have tried applying credentials directly, getting the: "The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials."

Comment: After I tried creating the New-PSDrive using credentials, but the write operation is still denied

Comment: Is it really a permission problem or is some process locking the file maybe?

Comment: Check the attributes of the config.xml file. It may have been set as Read-Only, or System. `Set-Content` also has a `-Force` switch which allows overwriting a read-only file. It does not override security restrictions however.

Comment: It is not read only, nor system. -Force does not work.
The problem is this is in the system protected folder "Program Files", and requires elevated command prompt to work. I am looking to get elevation from non-gui ssh environment, as stated in the question. Normal elevation requires gui environment to present the window to ask for elevation - which is impossible from ssh.

Comment: Also documentation states this: "The Force parameter does not override security restrictions."